# add javascript to wordpress page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I want to add filmstrip to my page that scrolls images without using a plugin. So I found nice javascript online (http://jsfiddle.net/benknowles/TUwqn/2/) that does exactly what I want to do. Here is the script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#filmstrip').filmstrip({
        interval : 3000
    });
});
```

Here is what I have done so far. I uploaded the javascript to my server and added  in my footer in WordPress. Then I copied the HTML as from the example on http://jsfiddle.net/benknowles/TUwqn/2/ and just replaced with location of my images. Added the css as from the example but I just can't get it to display correctly.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `.filmstrip()` isn't a built-in jQuery function -- it's a plugin. https://rawgit.com/benkno/jquery-filmstrip/master/js/jquery.filmstrip.js

Comment: Should be following proper documented wordpress conventions for enqueuing new scripts from a child theme functions file

Answer (score 0):

As [j08691](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616443/j08691) alluded to, you need to include [this file](https://rawgit.com/benkno/jquery-filmstrip/master/js/jquery.filmstrip.js) in your html before the code block:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#filmstrip').filmstrip({
    interval: 3000
  });
});
```

Which gives you access to the `filmstrip` function

Comment: Thanks guys, let me try this and get back to you.

Comment: Any word on progress with this? Is it an accepted answer?

Comment: I could not get it working no. Found another plugin that worked for me.